# FFMPEG: Getting error ./index0.ts Invalid data found when processing input file

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am getting this error when I run ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.2-2021-02-27-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[concat @ 00000179eed9e0c0] Line 1: unknown keyword './index0.ts'
./index0.ts: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Here is how my input file looking like(The ... is here to denomated that there's more lines)

```
./index9.ts
./index90.ts
./index91.ts
./index92.ts
./index93.ts
./index94.ts
./index95.ts
./index96.ts
./index97.ts
./index98.ts
./index99.ts
...
```

Here are the argument I use: `ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i ./mylist.txt -c copy output.ts^ ^X`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has to be the keyword before the filename.

`./index9.ts` --> `file ./index9.ts`